# NET::HTTP call fails from ssl when in rails envrionment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have some code that makes a few `Net::HTTP` calls some over `https` This code works fine when used in `irb`

however, when used from `rails` or the `rails console` I get an error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
from /Users/kevzettler/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918:in `connect'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoided the issue by passing a SSL verification manually like following code.

```
  uri = URI(@url)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)

  response = Net::HTTP.start(
    uri.host, uri.port, 
    :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
    :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |https|
      https.request(req)
    end
```

Quoted from here: https://github.com/matsubo/web_update_checker/blob/master/lib/web_update_checker.rb#L44